# How to send csrf token via postman

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-security, postman

I created the backend with spring boot where there is a need for csrf token.
I am trying to test my api using postman.

When i tried to call my api I am getting this error message

```
{
    "timestamp": 1427179894398,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?",
    "path": "/xxxx"
}
```

So, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "guess" CSRF token which most probably is just hidden input rendered inside the form.

So the most straightforward way is to get page with form with one request, parse the page to get CSRF token from form's input next and send it among other data in next request.

But this is tricky and unstable way(especially about looking up for CSRF token among HTML code with different forms and fields).

The better way is to implement "API mode" for your end points where some secret key would be passed through headers and suppress CSRF check. Actually have no idea how it should be implemented in Spring Boot with minimum efforts.